# How to create grid layout dynamically for XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

In my app I am trying to create a grid layout dynamically but not getting expected output:

Below is the code that I tried:

```
        Grid LayoutGrid = new Grid();


        //Created Two Columns
        ColumnDefinition gridCol1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition gridCol2 = new ColumnDefinition();

        LayoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol1);
        LayoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gridCol2);

        Grid Col1Grid = new Grid();
        //Create Two Rows
        RowDefinition gridRow1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition gridRow2 = new RowDefinition();

        Col1Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow1);
        Col1Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow2);

        Grid.SetColumn(Col1Grid, 1);

        return LayoutGrid;
```

The layout I am trying to create is like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: I only get two column, rows are not getting create in column 1.

Comment: You are not adding Col1Grid to your LayoutGrid

Comment: you are creating 2 different grids, try adding your rowdefinitions to your "Layout Grid"

Answer (score 0):

I added some colors to be easier to understand

```
private Grid CreateGrid()
    {
        var LayoutGrid = new Grid { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) };

        //Created Two Columns
        LayoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        LayoutGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        //Created Two Rows
        LayoutGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        LayoutGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        // region 1 - vertical left
        var stack1 = new StackPanel {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(stack1, 0);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(stack1, 2);
        LayoutGrid.Children.Add(stack1);

        // region 2 - top right
        var stack2 = new StackPanel
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(stack2, 1);
        LayoutGrid.Children.Add(stack2);

        // region 3 - bottom right
        var stack3 = new StackPanel
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(stack3, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(stack3, 1);
        LayoutGrid.Children.Add(stack3);

        return LayoutGrid;
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="Red" Grid.RowSpan="2"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Background="Green" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```